# Chemnum does not work since last l3package udpate

Tags: chemnum

I am using `chemnum` package and since last updates of `l3packages`, `l3kernel` and `l3experimental` when I compile my code there are 14 errors. The first one is:

> LaTeX error: "kernel/command-not-defined"
>
> Control sequence \chemnum_aux_file undefined

Despite this error the code is working and it gives me a good output, but this error should mean something:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report} %environnement du document
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %prise en charge des caractères spéciaux
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} %langue
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx} %prise en charge des graphiques eps
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\geometry{margin=55pt} %marges
\usepackage{indentfirst} %indentation après le titre de section
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} %bas de page en toute fin de page
\usepackage{csquotes} %pour la biblio
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs,subentry,maxnames=20]{biblatex} %style acs
\bibliography{library}  
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chemnum,chemstyle,chemscheme}%pour les schémas de chimie
%\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}  %prise en charge de l'écriture chimique
 

   

\begin{document}

\begin{scheme}[H] %le H permet de fixer l'image ici
    \centering
        \cmpdref{CM52}
        \cmpdref{CM53}
        \cmpdref{CM54}
        \cmpdref{CM55}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.80]{schema/13.eps}
        \caption{}
        \label{13} %permet de faire reference dans le texte
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: A number of things appear to have been broken by recent updates to l3kernel and l3packages. For example, I (and others) are finding that unicode-math no longer works as it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already fixed that and sent an update to CTAN. [Version 0.5c is already available there](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemnum).

Comment: Ok, I will update teh package

Comment: @cgnider Could I check exactly what broke: we did try to avoid any issues, so I wonder which change in the code caused this.

Comment: @JosephWright `chemnum` writes the compound numbers to an aux file `\chemnum_aux_file:` and `chemnum` was missing a `\iow_new:N \chemnum_aux_file:` so this was rather a bug in `chemnum`, I guess.

Comment: @JosephWright in another of my packages I had troubles, though, as it was relying on `xparse`'s (now missing) `\NoValue` to fool some commands to be fed with no value instead of an empty one. I fixed that, too, and probably should have designed the function using it differently in the first place, so ...

Comment: @cgnieder On the first point: OK, that was one of the 'breaking' changes we knew about. On the second point: Part of the reason for the change was that having `\NoValue` 'accessible' was asking for trouble, as there was the danger of people doing `\foo[\NoValue]` which was never the intention. So again this is 'to be expected'. I assume you are on LaTeX-L if only to pick up my announcements?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes I am and I was aware that I probably would have to adapt. After all it were only small changes I had to make.