# 7-2012 l3kernel & l3packages updates | 'broken'?

Tags: miktex, latex3, expl3

After installing recent updates to `l3kernel` and packages (both packaged 2012-07-19) on my MikTeX 2.9 system, several things seem to have broken:

1. docs relying on `unicode-math` no longer compile properly (math fonts all upright, not italic)

see - [Cambria Math becomes plain Cambria](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/cambria-math-becomes-plain-cambria)

2. `chemnum` also seems to have stopped functioning properly

see- [Chemnum does not work since last l3package udpate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64653/chemnum-does-not-work-since-last-l3package-udpate)

So, beyond the specifics of the issue, when this sort of thing happens, what is the preferred course of 'reporting' such a problem? is there a way to get older versions of a package, to 'roll back' to confirm that the problem originates with the 'newest version' of a package?

**Quick additional comment**: although not a rigorous test - a colleague who is 'celver' enough not to have update l3kernel and l3packages reports no problem with compilations. Again, not rigorous, but consistent with my working hypothesis that l3kernel and l3packages updates are the culprit.

Comment: I would contact the respective package authors. The documentation usually contains a contact email address.

Comment: You may find the [Automated Mercurial Repositories of CTAN](http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/) of use.  (Never had a call to use it myself, but I'm glad to know it's there.)

Comment: Will Robertson (author of `unicode-math`) is aware of the update and I am sure will update the CTAN version in a few days. As noted in the linked thread, `chemnum` has already been updated on CTAN. My own `siunitx` has already been updated on CTAN to use the updated `l3kernel` code, and to check that it is in use. Keeping packages absolutely 'in sync' is always tricky as synchronised release to CTAN does not guarantee the same will happen in TeX Live or MiKTeX.

Comment: For LaTeX3 code specifically, the development version is available from https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror. You can use this to install basically any arbitrary version using `make localinstall`: the log shows when we are sending snapshots to CTAN.

Comment: See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55614/update-install-the-newest-version-of-latex3

Answer (score 4):

Updates in `l3kernel` required matching changes in packages using LaTeX3 coding conventions. Both `chemnum` and `unicode-math` have now been updated on CTAN and in TeX Live, and should be updated in MiKTeX too pretty soon (there can be a week or so delay there).

Comment: For reference, I can add that `morewrites` was broken, even though I had uploaded it to CTAN the same day as the l3 bundles.  A fixed version which works with the new `l3kernel` will go on CTAN soonish.